# NSPredicate to filter out all items that are in another set

Tags: objective-c, ios, nspredicate, nsset

Is there any way to do this? I have a set of items that I want to exclude from another set. I know I could loop through each item in my set and only add it to my filteredSet if it's not in the other set, but it would be nice if I could use a predicate.

The set of items to exclude isn't a set of the same type of object directly; it's a set of strings; and I want to exclude anything from my first set if one of the attributes matches that string.... in other words:

```
NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.questionChoices.count];

BOOL found;

for (QuestionChoice *questionChoice in self.questionChoices)
{
    found = NO;

    for (Answer *answer in self.answers)
    {
        if ([answer.units isEqualToString:questionChoice.code])
        {
            found = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!found)
        [filteredArray addObject:questionChoice];
}
```

Can this be done with a predicate instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This predicate format string should work:

```
@"NONE %@.units == code", self.answers
```

Combine it with the appropriate NSArray filtering method. If `self.questions` is a regular immutable NSArray, it would look something like

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NONE %@.units == code", self.answers]

NSArray *results = [self.questions filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

If it's an NSMutableArray, the appropriate usage would be

```
[self.questions filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Be careful with that last one though, it modifies the existing array to fit the result. You can create a copy of the array and filter the copy to avoid that, if you need to.

Reference:
[NSArray Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/filteredArrayUsingPredicate:)
[NSMutableArray Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/filterUsingPredicate:)
[Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1)

Comment: Awesome, "NONE" worked perfectly. What I was missing was that I didn't realize I could just pass in an Array or Set to the predicate format like you would any other object. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example given by Apple for using [predicates with arrays](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-CJBDBHCB).  It employs filteredArrayUsingPredicate.

Comment: I know that I need to use filteredArrayUsingPredicate, but I don't know how a predicate can check if a different array contains a certain value.

Comment: Apologies, itchy trigger finger.  Can you use a sub-query with a 2nd predicate, kind of like this: http://www.answerspice.com/c119/1665179/can-an-nspredicate-search-for-an-object-within-an-array-owned-by-an-object-in-another-array?